# Are "matte PLA" filaments abrasive?

Tags: filament, nozzle, print-material

I picked up a roll of Overture matte black PLA, and the surface of both the filament and the printed object *feel like* paper. This made me wonder if it contains wood-based fibers like "wood PLA" does, and if so, whether it's abrasive and harmful to the nozzle. In the past I wouldn't have cared, but I'm using a CHT now and would like to avoid ruining it since it's expensive and I don't have spares sitting around.

Answer (score 3):

You may be experiencing the feel of paper, which is typically a matte surface, when feel testing the printed item, as both would be matte. A search for your focus found one purchaser of this product (via Amazon) has [left an answer addressing this question](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/asin/B089S2QDHD/2/ref=ask_dp_iaw_ql_hza?isAnswered=true#question-Tx2BUDAMGRBE1M0). The answer is on the last page of Q/A and is accompanied by another answer suggesting the white filament is abrasive. One has to click "see 2 more answers" in order to locate the quoted answer.

His reply was that he has printed 8 spools and found no deterioration of his nozzle.

> Not any more than any other PLA. I've gone through 8 rolls of this PLA so
> far with no noticeable degradation of my nozzle. D. DAmico · September
> 30, 2021

My own suspicion is that the filament has a chemical additive to create the matte finish, rather than any particulate that might cause abrasion.

Comment: This answer would be great with a link to the review (and quotation of the relevant part). There are so many I can't find it.

Comment: Since then I've found (and lost) some other reviews where folks claimed, with photos supposedly providing evidence, that matte PLA did destroy their nozzles. So I think this topic is still open...

Answer (score 0):

At least one filament manufacturer, Protopasta, documents their ["matte fiber HTPLA"](https://www.proto-pasta.com/collections/all/products/high-performance-htpla-matte-fiber) as "containing plant fibers" but also documents that

> Matte Fiber does NOT require a wear resistant nozzle.

So I think fred_dot_u's suspicion that the finish is produced by a chemical additive is probably false; it looks like these finishes are created with something similar to wood, but softer than brass so that it's non-abrasive.

This also suggests that matte finish filaments (at least the ones that feel paper-like) might have additional benefits beyond cosmetic, such as the fibers helping to resist warping while the extruded material is cooling, which seems to match my experience using it (less sensitive to cooling performance than normal PLA).